# Unable to delete the entire folder using RMDIR

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I have a code to delete the entire folder like:

```
REM : Copy Tomcat files
C:
rmdir /s /q "C:\Apache Software Foundation\webapps\ProjectFolder\"
```

The above code is deleting everything inside the ProjectFolder but not the folder itself. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no hidden/protected or still opened files which can't be deleted? Usualy this only happens if the folder is not empty. Do you get any error message?

Comment: The most likely cause is that one or more processes are using that folder as their current directory.

Answer (score -1):

remove the last slash '/'
[Windows Documentation help](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rmdir.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Before posting an answer you should check if it works or not. `rmdir` removes the whole folder with or without the last "\".